# Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at row 148480 with groupby function (dask)

Tags: pandas, parsing, dask

I'm working with a dask dataframe and as I want to apply the groupby method, I get the following Parse Error :

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at row 148480

I'm pretty new to python, I don't see how to fix a parsing Error that occurs when using a method

here's my code :

df1 = df.groupby('date')[['compound score']].mean().compute()

where date (srting) and compound score (float) are two columns of df (a dask dataframe)
Each date appears in many rows of the dataframe, that's why I want to use the groupby method.

I was expecting df1 to be a new dask dataframe with only 2 columns, the date and the mean of compound score for each date. Instead I get the parsing error.

I see many people are having this issue with pandas.read_csv(), but none with the groupby method.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .  We need to see your full code, and at least a sample of the data, so we can repeat what you did, and a full stack-trace.

Comment: Your problem seems to be data specific. Please try to recreate the problem on a smaller dataset and post the source code and the sample dataset which reproduces this problem.